# Can't access my hidden service

Tags: onion-services, ubuntu, website

I have tried nginx and apache2. I have configured everything according to all the guides and my hidden service still won't come up. I've done port forwarding to the port I want apache or nginx to redirect to and still nothing. I have a few bitcoin and would be willing to donate if someone can help me get this working. I'm on Ubuntu 14.0.4.

My `torrc` reads:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 6666 127.0.0.1:7777
```

and the Apache2 config has the following components.
`sites-enable/default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:6666>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`apache2/ports.conf`

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:6666
Listen 127.0.0.1:6666

<IfModule ssl_module>
    NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443
    Listen 127.0.0.1:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443
    Listen 127.0.0.1:443
</IfModule>
```

`apache2.conf`

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a copy of your torrc file, together with a copy of either your Nginx config file, or Apache2 config file - whichever one you're using.

Comment: Will do. Give me about an hour or so. Still at work. The files are on my home pc.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. But Ive added my configs to post.

Comment: Can you access http://127.0.0.1:6666/? What happens when you try to access your hidden service with the onion URL: http://onionurl.onion:7777/? Please substitute the latter with the correct URL.

Comment: Yes 127.0.0.1:6666 works. Havent tried adding 7777 after the onion url. Didnt even think about that. Ill try it tonight after work.

Comment: Just tried the .onion:7777 and its not working either. So Im guessing its a problem with my tor config? Or is it my listen config in apache?

Comment: Any advice would be greatly appreciated. No idea why I cant figure this out.

Comment: Do I need to change the localhost ip in all my configs to just my local ip? Think thats whats confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:6666
>   Listen 127.0.0.1:6666

Your server listens to port 6666 ..

> HiddenServicePort 6666 127.0.0.1:7777

.. but your Tor tries to connect to 7777

You should change your `HiddenServicePort` directive to
`HiddenServicePort 6666 127.0.0.1:6666`
or even
`HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:6666` (in this case, you don't have to put a port number in the .onion url.)